# cakephp code completion in Netbeans with "$this->" before a Helper

Tags: cakephp, netbeans

Code completion works only if I use:

```
/* @var $html HtmlHelper  */

$html->link...
```

but I want it to work while using

```
$this->Html->...
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This won't be possible with the current setup. If you want code completion like that, you could put the following at the top of your class (in the constructor maybe).

```
if (false) {
   $this->Html  = new HtmlHelper();
}
```

This will give you autocompletion, and since the IF condition never evaluates to TRUE it won't mess up your code.